# Migrate from Sublime text 2 to Sublime text3

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I need to migrate from sublime text 2 to sublime text 3 to have all the same configuration/plugins I have installed on the sublime text2.

I installed sublime text 3, but it does not have any of the sublime text 2 packages and settings. I really dont know if there are any straight forward methods to migrate or just copy of some folders.

Comment: Sublime Text keeps all of its settings and plugins in one config folder. Also, Sublime Text 3 uses Python 3 instead of Python 2, so your plugins may not work. It's still in beta.

Comment: Okay. Then should i need to re install all my plugins? For settings, can i copy and paste some folder? If it is, which folders to be copied (for OSX)?

Comment: You will need to install your plugins, and depending on which ones you use, you may need to wait for ST3 support. There's a handy list here: https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/wiki/Sublime-Text-3-Compatible-Packages

Comment: Check out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nsp6HxULU1Q

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I wrote a blog post detailing how to migrate over from Sublime Text 2 over to ST3.

Read: ["Can I use ST3 yet? Migrating to Sublime Text 3"](http://wesbos.com/migrating-to-sublime-text-3/)

*TLDR:*

1. Use git to install the python3 branch of Package Control. Step by step instructions [available here](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation#ST3);
2. Move over all your folders in `Sublime Text 2/Packages/` to `Sublime Text 3/Packages/` except two: `Default` and `Package Control`.

Comment: +1, I was having issues when was copying all Packages folders (`default` and `package control` also). While I know it''s good for your google analytics to have people going into your website, would be better for SO to have at least the two step you have posted. Dunno if your post will be deleted/unavailable someday.

Comment: Extract from https://sublime.wbond.net/docs/syncing: you actually do __not__ want to sync the whole _Packages/_ and _Installed Packages/_ folders ... The proper solution is to sync only the _Packages/User/ folder_

Comment: Since this was written Sublime text has now made it easy to install Package Control in Sublimetext 3 minus any of the git stuff, follow the official instructions for that part https://sublime.wbond.net/installation

Comment: Thx for this post - used every step and migrated with 0 problems.

Comment: Video is a bit out of date now, the package manager has an install that involves pasting some Python code into the python console.

Comment: @wesbos Video on the related page is broken - https://wesbos.com/migrating-to-sublime-text-3/ Here you go found the video as well - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nsp6HxULU1Q

Answer (score 5):

Your preferences/configuration from ST2 is in Packages/User (find it with Preferences -> Browse Packages). You can just copy that folder to to Packages folder in ST3.

About plugins it is best to check the already mentioned link: https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/wiki/Sublime-Text-3-Compatible-Packages
This wiki page explains which plugins can be installed via Package Control and which ones require manual installation.

Comment: Link content: "This page has been removed since Package Control 2.0 has been released and automatically presents appropriate packages based on what version of Sublime Text you are using." New link redirects to: https://packagecontrol.io/

Answer (score 3):

Aditional info for windows users, to make `ST3` as the **default editor after migration**.

If you keep both versions or if you uninstall `ST2`... probably you will notice that you can't open files or associate `open with` by default with `ST3`.

> I think I can help you get *Open With/default editor* working.
>   The problem is that the Sublime Text uninstaller doesn't remove a particular registry entry referring to Sublime Text 2's sublime_text.exe, which prevents Windows from adding an entry for Sublime Text 3's sublime_text.exe.
>
> To correct it manually, open `regedit` and navigate to:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\
```

> find the **`sublime_text.exe`** entry, and delete it.   You should now be able to set Sublime Text 3 as the default editor for anything you want.

Source: [Re: Can't make default editor in windows](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13214#p51276) by @[kane_t](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=13436)

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the Python3 version of Package Control. Copy the [Sublime Text 3 code for Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st3), open Sublime's Console (`` Ctrl ` ``), and paste the code into the console.
2. Open your user's Packages directory for both Sublime Text versions from the menus using  `Preferences` > `Browser Packages...` in Sublime Text. (`Sublime Text` > `Preferences` > `Browser Packages...` on OSX.)
3. In the ST2 Packages directory, copy all directories except these two: `Default` and `Package Control`. Paste all those directories into the ST3 Packages directory.
4. Restart Sublime Text 3.
5. (Optional.) Move your terminal / command prompt aliases to ST3.

   - Windows: Edit `autoexec.bat` in your user directory. Change `doskey subl="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe" $*` to `doskey subl="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" $*`. Save `autoexec.bat` and restart your command line interface.
   - OSX: Remove the old alias by executing `sudo rm  /bin/subl` in the terminal. Add a new alias with `sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /bin/subl`.
6. (Optional) Enter your license key into ST3. From the menus, choose `Help` > `Enter License` and paste in your license key.

See Wes' blog post on how to migrate over from Sublime Text 2 over to ST3 for more details: ["Can I use ST3 yet? Migrating to Sublime Text 3"](http://wesbos.com/migrating-to-sublime-text-3/)

Comment: [5](1) `autoexec.bat` ??.. could you please be a little more specific about *`windows version`*

Comment: @gmo - On my Win7, I use autoexec.bat to define doskey (aka aliases) on every start of the command prompt. Have you found this not to work in other versions of Windows?

Comment: w7x64, didn't know that you can still use it. But surprise me that you include that file in the answer, look's like a standard one for these days, and as far as I know, it's not. But I'm curious... Will read more about it. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

See if you plugins have been converted:  *[www.caniswitchtosublimetext3.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20130726231907/http://www.caniswitchtosublimetext3.com/) is no longer available*

ST3 and ST2 are in separate folders, so you can go ahead and install it and add your plugins/prefs as you work.